# Add multiple 2 element Lists to 1 list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to get output in the form:

```
Result = [[5,2.23607], [4,2.0], [3,1.7321]] ;
```

The idea of the program is that you input two numbers, N and M.

N is always greater than M.

The program finds the square root of the numbers from N to M (inclusive).

The above `Result` would be the result of the function `sqrt_finder(5,3,Result)`.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this but don't understand the recursive appending process.

Even if I did get this working, I don't think the output would be in the format I require.

This is what I have so far.

```
sqrt_finder(N,M,Result) :-
   N is M,
   Y is sqrt(N),
   Result = [N,Y].
sqrt_finder(N,M,Result) :-
   X is N-1,
   Y is sqrt(N),
   append([N,Y],sqrt_finder(X,M,Result),Result).
```

Can anyone please help explain the `appending` process and how the variable `Result` factors into this?

Thank you for your help.

**Update**

```
sqrt_finder(N,N,[[N,Y]]) :-
   Y is sqrt(N).
sqrt_finder(N,M,[[N,Y]|Result]) :-
   N > M, 
   X is N-1,
   Y is sqrt(N),
   sqrt_finder(X,M,Result).
```

Comment: You need to make it more clear what `sqrt_finder(N, M, Result)` is actually intended to do. For some good exercises in processing lists and to get the hang of handling the recursion process, I would suggest checking the list processing problems in [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/).

Comment: @lurker I have updated the question. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Do you mean maybe `sqrt_finder(Upper, Lower, R)`? You need an argument for the result, Prolog predicates are not functions that can return arbitrary values.

Comment: @Boris Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for appending anything or `append`.  And please do pay attention to the link by @lurker: there are solutions for all exercises, in case you haven't noticed. For example, P22 is a variation of what you need, namely, integers in a range.

Comment: @Boris Thanks for your comment. I went over the P22 example and used `trace` to see what was happening. I have tried to adapt that code to my situation (update above). Not quite there yet.. Still trying to work out how the `appending` process works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should remove the original code, leave the improved version in its place, and _show the actual query and output_ as you get them when you try to evaluate your `sqrt_finder/3` from the top level. Then, please _state the exact problem_: you have the predicate definition, you get this, but expected something else. Then ask how to get it, if it is still unclear.

Comment: @lurker for some reason it is a decreasing range.... I guess to make it marginally more difficult to copy-paste the solution.

Comment: @Boris ah right, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Archer in your updated solution, you have two issues: (1) you don't compute `sqrt(N)` (I assume based upon your original problem statement, you want the values, not just the `sqrt(N)` term in your list), and (2) You need to check the condition that `N > M` in your second clause to avoid an infinite recursion.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for your comment. 1) Yes, I'm still trying to figure out how to do that. 2) In the exercise we were told that the input would be such that N was always greater than M. But yes, this is a good point.

Comment: You computed the square root in your first code example. I'm not sure why you didn't use the same method in your updated example.

Comment: Your latest solution is still missing the `N > M` check in the second clause. It's required if you don't want to overflow on backtracking. Even though on input `N > M` will be true, you keep subtracting 1 from `N` in the recursion, so it will eventually not be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try and break it down to exactly what you specified in your question (not saying this is the most elegant solution, just trying to keep it simple):

> The idea of the program is that you input two numbers, N and M where N is always greater than M.

```
main(N,M,Result) :-
    N > M,
    calc_roots(N,M,Result).
```

> The program finds the square root of the numbers from N to M (inclusive).

I'm guessing this is an assignment and the fact they are asking to now include M into your calculations is to make it a little bit more difficult given the first condition was that N should always be greater than M. Again, there are several ways to accomplish this, but we're going for the simple approach.

We write down the possible states:

-N is less than M, this is <s>an invalid condition</s> our termination condition when decreasing N to calculate all the square roots from N to M included and we must stop the execution here.

-N is greater than or equal to M, in this case we want the square root of N and decrease it by 1 to recursively keep doing the same until we reach our base case we defined above.

```
% Base case
calc_roots(N,M,[]) :- N < M.

% N is greater than or equal to M (we need M inclusive)
calc_roots(N,M,[[N,Sqrt]|Result]) :-
    N >= M,
    - calc square root -
    - decrease N -
    - make recursive call with new N -
```

Up to you to fill in the blanks. Good luck!

Comment: If `N` is less than `M` is an *invalid condition*, why does `calc_roots` succeed in that case?

Comment: All Prolog predicates that deal with ranges are with both limits included: `between/3`, `numlist/3`, clp(fd) notation....

Comment: Invalid condition was not the best choice of words, I meant the termination condition when N becomes smaller than M while decreasing by one. I edited the answer.

Comment: I considered using between/3 in the example, but as OP stated he's been trying to figure out how to do it in a recursive process, I thought this easy-to-understand example would suit him better.